# currency conversion when direct mapping is not provided

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables @tbl_curr_master and @tbl_curr_trans b

I @tbl_curr_master, I have master data from each currency to some other currency with a conversion rate of the source to target currency.

the second table, @tbl_curr_trans i have some amount of each currency and I want to convert all the amount to EUR only in some cases mapping is provided directly 
where I can join directly on the basis of a.curr_name=b.from_curr and can get required data but in some cases where direct mapping is not provided 
like in INR to EUR there is no such direct mapping but what I can do is I can first compute USD and then compute EUR.

Please suggest how can I do it in an efficient manner in tsql query.

```
declare @tbl_curr_master table (id int  ,from_curr char(5), to_curr char(5),conversion_rate float )

insert into @tbl_curr_master(id, from_curr,to_curr,conversion_rate)
values(1,'usd','eur',0.28999),(2,'inr','usd',2.3645),(3,'chk','eur',0.56977),(4,'chk','eur',0.56977)


declare @tbl_curr_trans table (id int , curr_name varchar(5), amount float)

insert into @tbl_curr_trans (id,curr_name, amount)
values(1,'inr',789000),(2,'usd',896666),(3,'chk',458888)


select a.id , a.curr_name ,b.to_curr,  a.amount/ b.conversion_rate
from @tbl_curr_trans a , @tbl_curr_master b 
where a.curr_name=b.from_curr
```

Comment: You should use meaningful aliases to avoid confusion. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3 And you should use ANSI-92 style joins, they have been around for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: You also really should avoid using floats when dealing with money. It is an approximate datatype and rounding errors can happen. People tend to get a little put off when that happens. Use numeric datatypes instead. That being said I don't understand what the problem is here.

Comment: This is a [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) problem, i.e. [shortest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem). Do you have any other constraints, e.g. shortest path, conversion rates closer to unity in hopes of reducing rounding errors, more stable currencies preferred, more liquid currencies preferred, ...?

Comment: I need a path to get EUR conversion rate from any currency, But maybe in some cases I need to find the best path to find some other target currency, I will have an input for this I will code accordingly then and put the variable in place of target currency. there could be many parents involve to find target currency.How should I proceed with it.please suggest.

Comment: You can start with selecting an [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Algorithms) and letting us know what specific problems you encounter in implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of remarks:

- You're better of using #temp-tables than @table-variables
- You're probably better off using the `JOIN` construction versus simply listing all tables in the `FROM` clause and then linking them together in the `WHERE`
- Your current construction simply converts as it finds, there is no indication what target currency you actually want

To do so I'd suggest to dump the data in a temp-table and use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to do the direct conversion, followed by an update to do the indirect conversion.

```
CREATE TABLE #curr_master  (id int  ,from_curr char(5), to_curr char(5),conversion_rate float )

INSERT INTO #curr_master  (id, from_curr,to_curr,conversion_rate)
VALUES (1,'usd','eur',0.28999),
       (2,'inr','usd',2.3645),
       (3,'chk','eur',0.56977),
       (4,'chk','eur',0.56977)

CREATE TABLE #curr_trans (id int , curr_name varchar(5), amount float)

INSERT INTO #curr_trans (id,curr_name, amount)
VALUES(1,'inr',789000),
      (2,'usd',896666),
      (3,'chk',458888)

DECLARE @target_curr char(5) = 'eur'

-- direct conversion
SELECT a.id , a.curr_name, to_curr = @target_curr, curr_amount = a.amount, to_amount = a.amount/ b.conversion_rate
INTO #result
from #curr_trans a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN #curr_master b 
             ON b.from_curr  =  a.curr_name
            AND b.to_curr = @target_curr


SELECT * FROM #result

-- update those we missed via usd
UPDATE #result
   SET to_amount = ( SELECT #result.curr_amount * to_usd.conversion_rate * to_eur.conversion_rate
                       FROM #curr_master to_usd, #curr_master to_eur
                      WHERE to_usd.from_curr = #result.curr_name
                        AND to_usd.to_curr = 'usd'
                        AND to_eur.from_curr = 'usd'
                        AND to_eur.to_curr   = @target_curr)
 WHERE to_amount IS NULL

SELECT * FROM #result
```

You probably can do this in 1 statement without need for the #results, but like this it's easier to follow IMHO.

PS: agreed, my UPDATE could have used `JOIN` too, but I somehow think it's more readable like this. (dang exceptions to every rule =)

Comment: there could be more cases where currency  don't have direct mapping with EUR and USD i want to find out best possible path to find out Curr to EUR mapping.This is quite possible that curr need to lookup multiple currency to find its way to EUR.

Comment: Then you'll need to write some kind of logic that figures out what conversion rates are available, find the 'optimal' one and apply that. Technically this doesn't sound overly complicated but it will take some time to write/figure out, not sure SO is the place to ask this.